# Trying to pass variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I want to pass the index variable from mapping to event change function.
Here is the code:

```
{this.data &&
  this.data.map((item, index) => (
    <tr className="table-info" key={index}>
      <td>{index}</td>
      <td>{item.namaPengirim}</td>
      <td>{item.namaPenerima}</td>
      <td>{item.jenisPengiriman}</td>
      <td>{item.berat}</td>
      <td>{item.volume}</td>
      <td>{item.Harga}</td>
      <td>
        <select
          onChange={(key, event) => {
            this.props.onProsesChange(key, event, index);
          }}
          value={this.props.proses}
          className="form-control"
        >
          <option></option>
          <option value="Delivered">Delivered </option>
          <option value="On Process">On Process</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

As you can see, the index variable is outside the `onchange` function. When I tried to pass it, it returns `undefined` in `console.log`.

this is my onProsesChange in App.js

onProsesChange( event , index){

```
   let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('proses'))
   console.log(data)
   console.log(this.state.proses)
   console.log(index)
   if(data && data[index]){
    data[index]=event.target.value   
    this.setState({...this.state,proses:data})
    localStorage.setItem('proses',JSON.stringify(data))
   }else{
    data[index]=event.target.value
    this.setState({...this.state,proses:[event.target.value]})
    localStorage.setItem('proses',JSON.stringify([data]))

   }
    
}
```

Comment: Scope only goes deep/inner not outer. If you want something outside, declare a variable outside and assign in when inside.

Comment: what do u mean by that? sorry i don't quite understand

Comment: `index` ***is*** in scope (of the *entire* array.map callback), so this looks ok here. Can you include `onProsesChange` in your question? Where and what are you console logging?

Comment: What is `onProsesChange`?

Comment: I added onProsesChange on my post.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The function signature doesn't match with how it is being called.

```
onProsesChange(event, index) {
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("proses"));
  console.log(data);
  console.log(this.state.proses);
  console.log(index);
  if (data && data[index]) {
    data[index] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ ...this.state, proses: data });
    localStorage.setItem("proses", JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    data[index] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ ...this.state, proses: [event.target.value] });
    localStorage.setItem("proses", JSON.stringify([data]));
  }
}

...

onChange={(key, event) => {
  this.props.onProsesChange(key, event, index);
}}
```

When called it is passed `key`, the `event` object, and finally `index`.

## Solution 1

Match up the signatures by also consuming `key`

```
onProsesChange(key, event, index) {
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("proses"));
  console.log(data);
  console.log(this.state.proses);
  console.log(index);
  if (data && data[index]) {
    data[index] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ ...this.state, proses: data });
    localStorage.setItem("proses", JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    data[index] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ ...this.state, proses: [event.target.value] });
    localStorage.setItem("proses", JSON.stringify([data]));
  }
}
```

## Solution #2

Match up the signatures by *not* passing `key`

```
onChange={(key, event) => {
  this.props.onProsesChange(event, index);
}}
```